# Can you set the animation speed of a QTreeWidget?

Tags: qt, pyside2, qtreeview, qtreewidget

You can set a `QTreeWidget` to animated with:

```
tree_widget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
tree_widget.setAnimated(True)
```

This will make the `QTreeWidgetItems` animate while they collapse and expand.

Is there a way to access and edit the animation speed, and type, in the same way you would a `QtCore.QVariantAnimation()`?

I would like to be able to change the speed and animation type (eg, `QtCore.QEasingCurve.Linear`) if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's track the source;

1. When we look for `animated` property we can [find out](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#animated-prop) it is actually part of QTreeView class.
2. So first we need to check if they provided a public method (may named set/addAnimation) to access/manipulate this property. But there aren't  any. (not totally true, see the update section)
3. Then we've to look into the source code of QTreeView. The property set at [line 910](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qtreeview.cpp#n910) as `animationsEnabled` flag.
4. When we look for where the action taken according to this flag is at [line 3096](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qtreeview.cpp#n3096) and [line 3113](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qtreeview.cpp#n3113)
5. And unfortunately these methods are part of [QTreeViewPrivate](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qtreeview_p.h) class which is not part of **Qt API** according to the doc-string:

> W A R N I N G
>
> This file is not part of the Qt API.  It exists purely as an
> implementation detail.  This header file may change from version to
> version without notice, or even be removed.
>
> We mean it.

So, I don't see a direct way to access or change it without touching and building source.

---

### **UPDATE**

I recently came across to a `widget-animation-duration` property in [Qt Style Sheet Reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) to override built-in animation duration values with style sheets and decided to append it here. However, which widgets are supported is poorly documented. Fortunately, I was able to find [related commit](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/commit/?id=04eba7b538072e2811f074bf66fd41f27c90b35c) with help of google hacking:

```
"widget-animation-duration" inurl:"code.qt.io"
```

> **Diffstat**
>
> -rw-r--r--    src/widgets/doc/snippets/code/doc_src_stylesheet.qdoc   4
> -rw-r--r--    src/widgets/doc/src/widgets-and-layouts/stylesheet.qdoc 16
> -rw-r--r--    src/widgets/itemviews/qcolumnview.cpp   6
> -rw-r--r--    src/widgets/itemviews/qtreeview.cpp 2
> -rw-r--r--    src/widgets/styles/qcommonstyle.cpp 5
> -rw-r--r--    src/widgets/styles/qstyle.cpp   9
> -rw-r--r--    src/widgets/styles/qstyle.h 1
> -rw-r--r--    src/widgets/styles/qstylesheetstyle.cpp 4
> -rw-r--r--    src/widgets/widgets/qtabbar_p.h 2
> -rw-r--r--    src/widgets/widgets/qwidgetanimator.cpp 4
> **10 files changed**, 41 insertions, 12 deletions

QColumnView and QWidgetAnimator classes has these lines and I was able to change duration of QColumnView animations when I tested.

```
if (const int animationDuration = style()->styleHint(QStyle::SH_Widget_Animation_Duration, 0, this)) {
    d->currentAnimation.setDuration(animationDuration);
```

**BUT:** QTreeView implementation only checks the flags existence but not using it's value **yet** because they animate it by rendering tree to pixmap and drawing it by pixels. We can assume they'll use it because this looks like a preparation for it:

```
animationsEnabled = q->style()->styleHint(QStyle::SH_Widget_Animation_Duration, 0, q) > 0;
```