# How to modify the animation speed of a QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I have found a similar question: [Can you set the animation speed of a QTreeWidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67500678/can-you-set-the-animation-speed-of-a-qtreewidget)

I tried adding to the stylesheet:

```
QTreeWidget {
    widget-animation-duration: 1000;
}
```

But the animation delay for collapse and expansion continued the same, I think the default value is 0.

Comment: I think you can't do this because you don't have access, but you can create your custom tree widget based on qt source code and there you set what animation you like. I mean if it is so important for you create your class for implementing treewidget

Comment: The answer of the similar question indeed states that "widget-animation-duration" exists, but that it is only used to enable/disable the animation of a `QTreeView`.

Comment: So, your best option is probably to alter the Qt source code, to correctly use the duration settings of the stylesheet or to expose it as a C++ member function of `QTreeView`. See also the research in the answer of the similar question.

Comment: @m7913d that part of the source affects all widgets not only the `QtreeWidget`

Comment: What do you mean with "that part of the source"? Which part?

Comment: @m7913d `if (const int animationDuration = style()->styleHint(QStyle::SH_Widget_Animation_Duration, 0, this)) {
    d->currentAnimation.setDuration(animationDuration);`

Comment: That code is found inside `QColumnView` and `QWidgetAnimator` only. Those classes are not related to `QTreeView` or 'all widgets'.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable animations using [isAnimated()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#animated-prop), but as far as I know, it is impossible to speed up the animations.